# Why app cannot display UILabel as a positive result after sending message using MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilabel, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my app I try to inform a sender, the message has been sent with success. When user sent the message I would like to display a `UILabel` in center point of my `viewController` with an information about "Your message has been sent". After 2.5 seconds I would like to remove this object from view. For this operation I use this part of code:

```
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {

switch result{      
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        print("ok")
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        print("ok")
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        print("ok")
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:

        let sentInfo = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height:   50))
        sentInfo.text = "Your message has been sent"
        sentInfo.textAlignment = .Center
        sentInfo.center = self.view.center
        sentInfo.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        sentInfo.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        sentInfo.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        self.view.addSubview(sentInfo)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.5, animations: { () -> Void in                
            sendedInfo.alpha = 0                
            }) { (b:Bool) -> Void in                
            sendedInfo.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    default:
         break

    }// end switch

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

In this case I don't know why I don't see a inform label after sending a message.

Comment: In your animation with duration your telling it to take 2.5 seconds to animate the alpha to 0 and then remove from screen afterwards, probably not what u want

Comment: Misread the removeFromSuperview one sorry, try changing the .alpha = 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange your code like this

> ```
>     dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { () -> Void in
>         switch result{
>         case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
>             print("ok")
>         case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
>             print("ok")
>         case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
>             print("ok")
>         case MFMailComposeResultSent:
>
>             let sentInfo = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height:   50))
>             sentInfo.text = "Your message has been sent"
>             sentInfo.textAlignment = .Center
>             sentInfo.center = self.view.center
>             sentInfo.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
>             sentInfo.layer.cornerRadius = 10
>             sentInfo.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
>             self.view.addSubview(sentInfo)
>
>             UIView.animateWithDuration(2.5, animations: { () -> Void in
>                 sentInfo.alpha = 0
>                 }) { (b:Bool) -> Void in
>                     sentInfo.removeFromSuperview()
>             }
>         default:
>             break
>
>         }// end switch
>     }
> ```

Comment: it wont work, the label will be still added to the dismissed view.

Comment: The issue is not because of label added as subview to the dismissed view. Its because that label adding code wont work while a dismiss acton occurs.

Comment: and even if it worked it would get dismissed and will not be visible. The code itself works on a view controller that doesnt dismiss anything.

Comment: i did, i wouldnt comment otherwise :D

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing your label because you are dismissing the view right after showing it. You need to show it in the parent view (The one that presented this view), I suggest passing a weak reference to this parent view in your class like

```
weak var parentViewController : ParentViewControllerWithFancyCallbackFunction?
```

then moving the label-showing code to some function in the parent view, like:

```
func showMsgSentLabel() {
    let sentInfo = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height:   50))
    sentInfo.text = "Your message has been sent"
    sentInfo.textAlignment = .Center
    sentInfo.center = self.view.center
    sentInfo.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    sentInfo.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    sentInfo.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    self.view.addSubview(sentInfo)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.5, animations: { () -> Void in                
        sentInfo.alpha = 0                
        }) { (b:Bool) -> Void in                
        sentInfo.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

and changing your switch to something like this:

```
var shouldShowSentLabel : Bool = false

switch result{      
case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
    print("ok")
case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
    print("ok")
case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
    print("ok")
case MFMailComposeResultSent:
    shouldShowSentLabel = true
default:
     break

}// end switch

dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:  {
   if shouldShowSentLabel {
      parentViewController?.showMsgSentLabel()
   }
} )

}
```

Comment: It looks nice but doesn't work. I tryed to make `weak var parentViewController : MyParentControllerName? in `MyParentControllerName  Class` and then I call it in `dismissViewController` as `parentViewController.showMsgSentLabel()`, but it doesn't work.
`

Comment: the `weak var parentViewController : MyParentControllerName?` should be in the view that gets presented

Comment: ok, but I present system's mailbox client, so i can't add it to this view.

Comment: but the switch is executed inside of the presented view? so you can modify it. When the parent presents it just set parentViewController to self